# Regex like parameter function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, parameters

I will do a function with parameters that get a regex and check the field of a form with it. 
I have this code:

```
//The first function handler (no one runs):
field.onblur = function(){
    checkField(0, /^([a-z ñáéíóúü]{2,60})$/i, "name", "nameError", "Error in name");
}

//The function:
function checkField(numForm, regex, idField, idError, error){

    var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[numForm];
    var field = form.getElementById(idField);
    var spanError = form.getElementById(idError); 

    //Since here runs, so I think the problem is with the regex
    if(!regex.test(idField.value))
        spanError.innerHTML = error;
    else
        spanError.innerHTML = "";
}
```

What is the proper way to make a function and give it a regex like a parameter?

Comment: What's the actual question here?

Comment: if you are using html5, there is a native validation method.

Comment: What is `idCampo.value`?

Comment: It doesn't look to me as if you're passing in a parameter value for "numForm"; your regex is the first parameter when you call "checkField".

Comment: getElementByTagName() => getElementsByTagName()

Comment: idCampo and getElementByTagName were mistakes of the post. I translate the variable names from the spanish after posting.

idCampo is idField (in spanish).Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regexp is passed fine, these two lines are erranous instead:

```
var field = form.getElementById(idField);
var spanError = form.getElementById(idError);
```

[`getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById) is a method of `document` only. You can fix the issue by using `id` string like below:

```
var field = form[idField];
var spanError = form[idError];
```

... or using `getElementById()`: `var field = document.getElementById(idField);`

Also this line (unless a typo in the post)

```
if(!regex.test(idField.value))
```

should be:

```
if(!regex.test(field.value))
```